# Vapor `Public` directory inside docker image is not exposed

Tags: xcode, docker, dockerfile, vapor, leaf

I'm running Vapor 4.3 and Leaf with Xcode on my Mac without any issues.

public directory middleware is enabled:

```
let fileMW = FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: directory)
app.middleware.use(fileMW)
```

as soon as I build the image using the default `dockerfile` and run it on the docker, the css and all image files are not loaded anymore.

**Note:** the `dockerfile` is the exact same one that came with the `vapor new` command. (Updated to the date of the writing this post)

**Safari** shows this error:

```
[Error] Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://127.0.0.1/styles/index.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
```

[image: resources]

**Chrome** shows this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://127.0.0.1/styles/index.css".
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to confirm what does your Dockerfile look like? And if you try to curl the file instead of using the browser what do you see?

Comment: Exactly the same default docker file that came with the `vapor new` command. Getting 404 with curl. @0xTim

Comment: The Dockerfile has changed over the months so you may have an old version that's needs changing. And do you have a file in `Public/styles` called `index.css`. Finally can you expand on `let fileMW = FileMiddleware(publicDirectory: directory)` - what's the directory property there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a **case sensitivity** issue! Mac has no problem finding files with this issue but Linux not!

> ⚠️ Even if you already set: `app.routes.caseInsensitive = true`, it  will not affect your resources requests.

So make sure you have set all paths exactly as they appear in `pwd` command.